# Select first option in angular 2

Tags: angular

How can i select the first option in the following Selection to the model programmatically?

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data" name="data" (ngModelChange)="onSortChange($event)">
          <option [ngValue]="{data:'car', color: 'green'}">green car</option>
          <option [ngValue]="{data:'engine', color: 'blue'}">blue engine</option>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get to the options using ViewChild and a local template variable.

Change the view like to add the local template.

```
   <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data" name="data" (ngModelChange)="onSortChange($event)">
      <option [ngValue]="{data:'car', color: 'green'}">green car</option>
      <option [ngValue]="{data:'engine', color: 'blue'}">blue engine</option>
   </select>
```

Then in the controller you can get to the options and set the selected attribute on the one you want to select.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('carSelect') carSelect: ElementRef;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    setSelected(): void {
        this.carSelect.nativeElement.children[0].selected = true;
    }
}
```